# socket.io-client-swift disconnect event can't handle

Tags: swift, events, socket.io

I'm using swift3 and i can't succeed to handle the "disconnected" event of SocketIOClient class.

https://github.com/socketio/socket.io-client-swift

[Docmentation Events][1]

In the documentation you can see that there is an event when socket is disconnected.

I tried using : 
`socket.handleEvent(<#T##event: String##String#>, data: <#T##[AnyObject]#>, isInternalMessage: <#T##Bool#>, withAck: <#T##Int#>)`

Can anyone help to handle this event!

Thank you !

Comment: can you please show your code ?